# Angular material radio button styles are not working

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm trying to add a mat-radio-button in my code.
But for some reason, the styles are not working, I dont have any class created neither overriding the radio buttons style.
The fill element is not centered and doesn't have the angular material style.

[image]

Previously I have added it to my app.module and imported in the component.
I'm using @angular/material: "6.3.0

```js
{
  "name": "petpo-fe-admin-dashboard",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "webdriver-manager update --versions.chrome=2.37 && ng e2e --webdriver-update=false",
    "docs": "typedoc --options typedoc.json --exclude '**/*+(e2e|spec|index|mock).ts' ./src/"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^6.3.0",
    "@angular/common": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^6.3.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^6.0.0",
    "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "0.1.0-10",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.0-11",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.1.0-11",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^2.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.1",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "crypto-js": "^3.1.9-1",
    "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.0.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.6.1",
    "@angular/cli": "~6.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~1.4.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typedoc": "^0.11.1",
    "typescript": "~2.7.2"
  }
}
```

```html
 <mat-radio-group aria-label="Select an option">
        <mat-radio-button value="1">Option 1</mat-radio-button>
        <mat-radio-button   value="2">Option 2</mat-radio-button>
      </mat-radio-group>
```

Comment: Could you add a bit more details? One would be the template code where you use the material button, another would be the styles that you use to modify it - and in which file the styles are set, and third would be your versions of Angular and Material.

Comment: Doesn't have any style added. It's empty

Comment: I assume you added the theme and all the other stuff from [here](https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started) as well? _Edit:_ can you try to reproduce this in a stackblitz?

Comment: yep @Zlatko, I onli have the material table working on this project, so this is the 2nd element that I need to add.

Comment: Can you show you `package.json` file in the question or reproduce the issue in a stackblitz?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and it happened due to the wrong installation of Angular Material, it asks some questions at the time of installation.
Command: `ng add @angular/material`
[These were the answers I gave to work correctly:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJGAD.png)

Comment: Welcome to stack**overflow**.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly, here's a CSS conflict somewhere with the internal elements of the `mat-radio-*` components. Inspect the inner elements to see where's the origin of the undesired margin or padding.